# How to create function in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE filedata_temp
(
 num serial NOT NULL,
 id integer,
 mydata character(25),
 the_geom geometry,
 CONSTRAINT filedata_pkey PRIMARY KEY (num)
)


CREATE TABLE filedata
(
 num serial NOT NULL,
 id integer,
 mydata character(25),
 the_geom geometry,
 CONSTRAINT filedata_temp_pkey PRIMARY KEY (num)
)
```

i want to make function which insert rows from first table in second table if this rows not exist in second table. Field for comparison tables is `num` field.

After reading some examples :

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  insert_into_wgs()
  RETURNS void AS
  $BODY$
  BEGIN
insert into filedata 
(
    id,
    mydata,
    the_geom,

)
values
(
    id,
    mydata,
    ST_TRANSFORM(the_geom,4326)
);
 end
 $BODY$
 LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

So i need some help/

**UPDATE**

i try this function(gods of data base's says me it)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  insert_into_wgs()
RETURNS void AS
$$
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO filedata (id,mydata,the_geom)  
 SELECT id,mydata,ST_TRANSFORM(the_geom,4326)
 FROM filedata_temp
 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM filedata);
end;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

But nothing insert in table filedata.

function calling

```
  ce_proc = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgis","postgres","123456");
  CallableStatement proc = (CallableStatement) ce_proc.prepareCall("{call insert_into_wgs()}");
  proc.execute();
```

Comment: My answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11797148/905902 here should provide enough material. It should be quite easy to change the trigger functions into ordinary functions. and the casts into the geom transformations you want.

Comment: Im already read your answer. Now i use simular function. Bit when i try use this in trigger i get a problem with function ST_TRANSFORM(). So now i want to create function to call it from java code.

Comment: You should provide ST_transform() with the correct arguments (the values from NEW.the_geom plus the srid you want). In my example I use a plain cast zvalue::text, or ztext::integer, you should use the st_tranform() function there instead. (possibly prefixed by the schema name eg public.st_transform() ) That's all.

Comment: i know what arguments st_transform() gonna get. Its function works when i call it in sql edidor or insert or update another table. But in my case its problem with srids. I update my previous question and u can see what st_transform() do with geometry.

Comment: BTW: why do the tables appear to have two keyfields (num, id) and only one (id) seems to be used, while the other (num) is defined as a primary key?

Comment: Its test tables, fields names means nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax to shove data from one table into another:

```
INSERT INTO filedata (...) SELECT ... FROM filedata_temp WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 FROM filedata WHERE filedata.num = filedata_temp.num
)
```

Of course the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` part is only one way to check for differences. Joining the table is another. Which is the best one depends on your actual data.

**Other Note**: Both tables have `num serial`. But shoving data from one table into the other this means that both `SERIAL`s are fighting each other. You should make that a plain `int` in the second table.

Comment: The two serials will be painful, but they could also use the same underlying sequence (as a default for a bigint column type) The "explicit" syntax will be a bit more complex.

Comment: @wildplasser: I know what you mean, but I think your wording is wrong: Since a `serial` is an `int` _together_ with a _new_ sequence you cannot create a `serial` with a "shared" sequence. You can create an 'int' column with a default using an existing sequence though. How the "ownership" of the shared sequence is handled... I don't know.

Comment: The only hard part will be the `owned by` part. But I think it only serves to establish the dependency (to enable `DROP ... CASCADE` to cascade to the sequence), so you could choose to do without the "owned by" part. That would leave the sequence orphaned on a `DROP table ... CASCADE`

Answer (score 0):

The most relevant section in the manual is [39.9. Trigger Procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html). The examples there, especially  *Example 39-4. A PL/pgSQL Trigger Procedure For Auditing* can be a better starting point than your current code.

Comment: @KliverMax: You might explain that a little bit more.

Comment: When i use a triggers function st_transform() not work becouse i try to put geometry with `srid=70066` in geometry column with `srid = 4326`.

Comment: @KliverMax: I don't see why this has anything to do with triggers or not.